# Is there comprehensive catalogue of black holes and relativistic jets?

Tags: black-holes, resource-recommendations, astronomy, relativistic-jets

Basically I am looking for a database with RJs and BHs characteristics.
In High Energy Physics there is Particle Data Group book which is updated regularly. Is there something similar?

Upd.2023-01-17: Related Question
[Gamma Ray Burst data](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256753/gamma-ray-burst-data)

Comment: I do not think observations have reached that stage . Have a look https://www.mdpi.com/journal/universe/special_issues/BHRJ

Comment: Previously I could not find this (perhaps wrong search criteria) list of GRB's. They are not linked to BHs or any super heavy objects, which requires an additional effort.

https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/w3browse/all/ipngrb.html

Comment: One more: https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0312314 (inside dead link to DB)

Comment: Third one: https://user-web.icecube.wisc.edu/~grbweb_public/index.html
automated. Perhaps there are overlaps with previous one.

Comment: To keep it in one place. Seems to be reference list to the above table
 https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/grbcat/references.html

Answer (score 2):

There is the [BlackCat](https://www.astro.puc.cl/BlackCAT/) catalogue of black holes in X-ray binary systems (basically all the known Galactic black holes apart from the supermassive central one).

The [GWTC-3](https://www.ligo.org/science/Publication-O3bCatalog/) catalogue is a compiled LIGO-VIRGO catalogue of detected merging compact binaries, which are almost all black holes.